# is there message getting method in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i want all the messages on a list but the error is value of type Future> can't be assigned to a variable of type List

```
SmsQuery smsQuery = new SmsQuery();
List<SmsMessage> msg = await smsQuery.getAllSms
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct syntax.

```
SmsQuery smsQuery = new SmsQuery();

Future<List> getMsg() async {
  List msg = await smsQuery.getAllSms();
  return msg;
}
```